# sprintf error in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, printf

I am working on a UDP socket program in windows visual studio.
I am getting an error for sprintf statement. How to correct it?
My code is:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 30;i++) //take-off
{
    printf("send AT*REF:take off\n");
            sprintf(command, "AT*REF=%d,290718208\r", seq++);



    rc = sendto(sd, command, strlen(command) + 1, flags, (struct sockaddr *) &droneAddr, sizeof(droneAddr));
    if (rc<0) {
        printf("%s: can not send data\n", argv[0]);
            return(1);
                    }
     }
```

The errors I am getting are :

```
Error   1 error C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
Error   1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__bind@12
Error   2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htonl@4 referenced in function _main 
Error   3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4
Error   4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__sendto@24
Error   5 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__socket@12
Error   6 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__gethostbyname@4
Error   7 error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Have you tried doing what the compiler tells you to?

Comment: ya i tried it. it is giving a lot of errors.                     Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__bind@12  
Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htonl@4 referenced in function _main  
Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4 
Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__sendto@24 
Error 5 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__socket@12 
Error 6 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__gethostbyname@4 
Error 7 error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals

Comment: An unrelated hint: When a function returns with an error (like when `sendto` return with `rc < 0`) then it might be a good idea to tell the user *what* the error was. It will certainly help you to understand what went wrong. Read about [`WSAGetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The compiler error, and your linker errors are unrelated.  Actually do try using sprintf_s instead.

Comment: Another unrelated thing: Are you sure that only carriage-return will be accepted as a newline? Not the carriage-return *and* newline sequence `"\r\n"`?

Comment: Note that the suggested `sprintf_s` is part of Annex K, which is unpopular and has been removed from the C standard library and isn't considered standard C; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50724726/4975230), if portability is a concern with your code (between OSes) you are probably better off using `sprintf`. IMO it's a bit heavy handed for Microsoft to treat using `sprintf` as an error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`printf` and its sister function `sprintf` are considered unsafe due to the amount of *undefined behaviour* they emit if used incorrectly.

Visual Studio is disabling these functions by default.

But, since they are part of the C++ standard library, you *can* use them. But Visual Studio will only allow you to do that if you include the line

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

before the relevant standard library headers are included.

Alternatively, include `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in your project preprocessor settings (which is what I do).

(By the way, Visual Studio is emitting a very helpful error message in this instance. Do try to learn to interpret them.)

Comment: I've clarified the placement location in my answer. For now, clobber it: put it in `stdafx.h`.

Comment: I would argue that defining that macro is a bad idea. The warnings are there for a reason. @wireless_lab Please read about [`sprintf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx), it's not much you have to change to make it work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Is making an important point here. Do try to use safer features of C++. I too would be inclined to obey the compiler and use the safer `sprintf_s`.

Comment: Defining `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` directive for my debug configuration works, it compiles, but defining it for my release build causes the error to persist. Any idea why?

Comment: What's unsafe / undefined about `printf`?

Comment: @SteveSummit:  if you give the incorrect type, for example an `int` to a `%s` format, then it *might* crash the program.  With `sprintf` the supplied buffer might not be large enough and overflow.

Comment: @cdarke Ah, okay.  To my mind, the possibility for mayhem with `sprintf` is qualitatively different from that for `printf`. `sprintf`'s glaring problem is easily fixed by switching to `snprintf` (or, if you're Microsoft, `sprintf_s`).  `printf`'s problems, though rarer, are more fundamental, and I don't know how to fix them (short of disallowing `%n`).  I don't know how a `printf_s` can be safer than `printf`, but that's my quibble with Microsoft, not you.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 3):

For most of the errors in your question you need to add `ws2_32.lib` to the library that the project links to  (in the VS project's `Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies` property).

Other answers/comments have addressed the `sprintf()` problem: either defined the macro `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` or use a version of `sprintf()` that is deemed safe by Microsoft, such as `sprintf_s()`.  I wish MSVC had a standard version of `snprintf()` that can be used (maybe soon - they're adding quite a bit of C99 stuff to the toolchain).