# Where is the scanf_s() buffer defined?

Tags: c, scanf, tr24731

If I didn't have access to the internet, but knew that I wanted to use the `scanf_s()` function to take input from the keyboard (`stdin`), how would I know where to declare the buffer?

At the moment, when I step into the `scanf_s()` function in Visual Studio, I see this:

```
#if __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__

    _Check_return_opt_
    _CRT_STDIO_INLINE int __CRTDECL scanf_s(
        _In_z_ _Scanf_s_format_string_ char const* const _Format,
        ...)
#if defined _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE // SCANF
    ;
```

So, I can see that `scanf_s()` takes 1 defined argument (`char const * _Format`) which, in this case, could be some placeholder such as be `"%s"`, but nothing for the second argument - the memory address of the buffer to store the result of the scanning.

Comment: It is not you who defines the buffer that takes the input; that is the OS. You define the buffer that receives the result of the scanning.

Comment: Sorry, thats what I mean.

Comment: No need to be sorry; hope this explanation answers your question.

Comment: The important part is called a variable argument list indicated by `...` after the last specified parameter.

Comment: if you "didn't have access to the internet", you'd have bigger problems than trying to remember function prototypes :-)

Comment: @Gerhardh , I understand that, but it seems awfully vague to have that in your arguments, right? If scanf was declared `scanf(char const * const _Format , char 
 * buffer)` , I think that would be a better indicator that scanf() accepted a buffer than leaving it out altogether

Comment: If `scanf` was declared that way it would not be able to scan more values or different values than exactly one single string. It would be a completely different function than what it is now.

Comment: @sharkbites `scanf(char const * const _Format , char * buffer)` would make usages like `int x; scanf("%d", &x)` a type mis-match.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf_s` takes a variable list of arguments. The first argument is mandatory, a string with the conversion specifications, the following arguments depend on what conversion specifications are present in the format string.

For each conversion specification `%s`, `%c` and `%[`, `scanf_s` expects 2 arguments for the conversion: a pointer to `char` (`char *`) and a number passed with type `rsize_t` that specifies the size of the array pointed to by the `char *` argument.

Here is an example:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[32];
    int res;

    printf("Type a word: ");
    res = scanf_s("%s", buf, sizeof(buf));
    switch (res) {
    case EOF:
        printf("Input failure\n");
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("Matching failure\n");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("Success: you typed '%s'\n", buf);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Unexpected return value %d\n", res);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that support for `scanf_s` is far from universal. Microsoft platforms usually support it, but with varying semantics, while linux and Mac C libraries usually don't. Read this question to understand  [Why didn't gcc implement _s functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724726/why-didnt-gcc-implement-s-functions/50724865#50724865)

Comment: "if the format string contains %s ..." --> may want to add `"%c"` and `"%["` to the list.

Comment: Note: [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) `*scanf_s()` uses a size of type `unsigned` and not `size_t` like the C spec's annex K.

Comment: @chux: really? This is the final blow on this ill fated extension.

Comment: Suggest  [Why didn't gcc implement _s functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50724865/2410359)