# Create accessible file from root privilege process

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, fopen

I'm having a bunch of processes from different privileges, all running a shared code that open (and create if needed) a file for write using fopen_s with "a+" flag.

However, since no permissions that supplied to this command, and a root process create the file first, than other non-root processes couldn't access this file.

I could use `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);` and thus control the file permissions (represented by mode_t) to allow access for everyone, but I need the file descriptor (`FILE *`) and not fileID. so I can use `FILE *fdopen(int fd, const char *mode);` in order to make the conversion.

Perhaps there's a more straight forward way to do it ?

Comment: A little nitpicking about terms, a `FILE *` is a C file stream (not to be confused with C++ stream objects), while the integer returned by e.g. `open` is a *descriptor* (in the case of `open` it's a file descriptor).

Comment: As for your problem, `open` followed by `fdopen` is probably the simplest and most straight-forward way, unless you want to bother with [`chmod`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html) after opening the file.

Comment: Lastly a little more nitpicking: There's no `fopen_s` function in the C, C++ or POSIX standards, it's a Microsoft Visual C++ CRT specific extension.

Comment: Hi, I've read about fopen_s here `https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen` so I assumed it also support posix.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is an `fopen_s()` in the **optional** Annex K of the C11 standard.  No significant implementation other than Microsoft's exists, and Microsoft's doesn't fully comply with the C standard anyway.

Comment: You could `fopen` with `chmod`, but that won't be atomic.

Comment: @IradK Read this for some data on the "safer" `*_s()` functions:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724726/why-didnt-gcc-implement-s-functions

Comment: @KamilCuk, perhaps you can provide simple code block to demonstrate your idea ?

Comment: @KamilCuk There is no atomic way to create a file with a guaranteed set of permissions.  The mode passed to `open()` is subject to modification via the `umask` setting, and that `umask` setting can be changed between its being set/checked and any subsequent call to `open()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could use int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode); and thus control the file permissions (represented by mode_t)

Not really.  Unless you set [your process's `umask` setting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html).  Because the permissions passed to `open()` are not the permissions the created file is necessarily created with.

[Per POSIX `open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (bolding mine):

> the access permission bits (see [`<sys/stat.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)) of the file mode shall be set to the value of the argument following the `oflag` argument taken as type `mode_t` **modified as follows**: a bitwise AND is performed on the file-mode bits and the corresponding bits in the complement of the process' file mode creation mask. Thus, all bits in the file mode whose corresponding bit in the file mode creation mask is set are cleared.

So

```
int fd = open( someFileName, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644 );
```

is **NOT** guaranteed to set the file permissions to `0644`.

If your file creation mask is set to `0077`, then the file will actually be created with permissions set to `0600`.

Note that the `umask()` setting is a process-wide property, and it's not really a good idea to change it much.  And if you're trying to write general-purpose code that has no side effects, it's a bad idea to change it at all.  For example, changing the `umask()` setting in a multithreaded process in order to allow wider access to files being created can cause 
security problems if another thread creates a file at the same time.

The best way to set file permissions to be exactly what you want is to set file permissions to be exactly what you want with [`fchmod()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmod.html):

```
FILE *f = fopen(...);
fchmod( fileno( f ), 0644 );
```

In fact, since the `umask()` setting is a process-wide property, it's always possible in general that it can be changed by another thread at any time, **so setting the permissions explicitly via `chmod()` or `fchmod()` is the only guaranteed way to get exactly the permissions specified in all circumstances**.

Comment: in your solution of calling `fchmod` right after `fopen`, should I check if the file was created or simply changing the permissions anyway ?

Comment: @IradK You'd need to check for success from `fopen()`, else making the `fileno()` call with a `NULL` parameter would potentially invoke undefined behavior, likely a `SIGSEGV` here.

Answer (score 2):

No. The technique you described (`open` followed by `fdopen`) is the correct way to achieve what you want to do. As Some programmer dude pointed out, you could call `chmod` from your program to change the file permissions after it's created, but that's a more roundabout way to do it.