# For some reason "printf_s" is producing error: "not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I downloaded MinGW-64 and ran this little snippet of code (shortened as it was originally a stack, queue and other DS implementations):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    const int _sizeS = 20;
    .
    .
    .
    int _tmp;
    printf_s("\nEnter an alpha-numeric character to quit: ");
    
    std::cin >> _tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles perfectly in VS2019, and does what I want it to.

However, I use `g++ pyrmd.cpp` at the command line and get an error:

```
pyrmd.cpp: In function 'int main()':
pyrmd.cpp:6:2: error: 'printf_s' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'printf'?
    6 |  printf_s("\n Enter a character: \n");
      |  ^~~~~~~~
      |  printf
```

Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening, and how to resolve it?

Comment: it means the compiler is unable to find printf_s function and probably it is a typo you probably want printf and not printf_s

Comment: There is no [printf_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function in standard C++.

Comment: The `printf_s` function was only made part of the [Standard C library at C11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Maybe you need to set your g++ compiler to use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724726/why-didnt-gcc-or-glibc-implement-s-functions

Comment: @SmitShah Just checked back. The `stdio.h` of MinGW64 doesn't  have the print_s version, but the VS2019 libraries do. So, yeah my mistake.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There's no [printf_s] in the MinGW64 _include libraries_. It is, however, present in the `stdio.h` of VS2019 libraries. Just looked into the header files in both of them.

Comment: @interjay Yup. Just discovered it myself. My bad. Guess, I'll stick VS2019 for now.

Comment: @AdrianMole As the person just below referenced a previous post and I found out looking at the header files in both GCC and VS2019, the [printf_s] is not present in GCC. Also, you're right. Just changed the compiler settings in VS2019 and got an error mountain.

Comment: You can just switch to the portable `printf` instead.

Comment: @SuperTC: Answers should be posted in the "Add Answer" section; they should never be edits to the question. It's OK to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @NicolBolas Will keep that in mind next time. Sorry, I'm noob at the moment.

Comment: @SuperTC My point is that there is no *standard* C++ function called `printf_s`.  A C++ compiler need not implement it -- there is no mandate to include this function.  Also, you cannot determine if there is an actual implementation of `printf_s` or any other function just because you see a declaration in the header.  All a header does is allow your code to *compile*.  When it comes to linking, that function actually needs to exist, and not just as a prototype or declaration.  So looking at a header and saying "that function exists" is not totally correct.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yup, you're right. But, widely used and officially (or rather, from Verified Publisher) documented functions can be verified by looking at the header files. If the function is deprecated, the compiler will produce a warning. My error was the lack of declaration in the given scope. And while the ```printf_s``` function is standard c library function, it was ported to c++ using the ```cstdio``` header. I was just messing around anyway. If it was an official project, I would have made different c files and c++ files and used functions that were more readily portable.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself and confirmed from the comments that the problem was with GCC itself.

The *include libraries* of GCC don't have the declarations for printf_s. Both the header files `stdio.h` and `cstdio` lack the declarations. VS2019 however has the MSVC compiler which provides the `_s` functions.