# Reading from scanf results to infinite loop

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

I'm trying to read information about students using `scanf()` in a for loop (`N` times -> `N` inputted by the user), but the `for()` loop goes more than that... it doesn't stop at all. I've tried all the combinations for the string formatting, but nothing seems to work.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct STUDENT_CONSTRUCTOR {
    char first_name[35], last_name[35];
    char gender;
    int grade;
} student;

int main(void) {
    int N; // number of entries

    student list[N];

    printf("Number of entries: "); scanf("%d", &N);

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("<Entry %d>\n", i);
        scanf("%d %c %s %s\n", &list[i].grade, &list[i].gender, list[i].first_name, list[i].last_name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to type in are sequences like the following:
`10 M Mateas Mario`, where "10" is the average grade, "M" the gender, "Mario" my first name and "Mateas", my last name.

`N` is properly read, and also the data inside the `list[]` array is properly read.
`list[]` is based on a structure that holds all these data types.

Still, whenever I type in a specific value for `N` (for example 3, 4, 5, etc.), `<Entry ...>` always goes beyond that number. Before telling me that `scanf()` is deprecated, I would like to know if there's a possibility of fixing this code without getting rid of the `scanf()` function. I don't want to use `fgets()` because I don't know the maximum number of characters the input contains.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `scanf()` isn't deprecated, but some coders prefer not to use it. But [there are ways](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+input+a+string+of+unknown+length+in+c+site:stackoverflow.com) to use `fgets()` when you don't know the line length in advance

Comment: And `scanf()` is often problemmatic, but I don't see any reason to think that it's responsible for the issue here.

Comment: Ah.  What do you think `student list[N];` does when it appears *before* a value for `N` has been entered?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh, there was the problem. Can you post it as an answer, so I can mark it as solved? Thank you so much :) My bad

Comment: Undefined behavior, voting to close as  a typo.

Comment: Another typical problem with using `scanf` and `%s` is when the first or last name consists of two words, such as 'Betty Sue Smith' or 'Peter Da Silva'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ...

> ```
>     int N; // number of entries
>
>     student list[N];
> ```

... you are using the indeterminate initial value of `N` to specify the dimension of `list`.  Undefined behavior results.  That UB is not constrained to manifest as an immediate failure or a noisy one.  In this particular case, it is manifesting as your iteration not stopping where you expect it to do.

Although it is not generally very fruitful to reason about the *mechanism* of a particular manifestation of UB, it nevetherless seems commonly to inspire some kind of perverse curiosity, so I will speculate that in your case, `list` is being given fewer elements than ultimately you request, maybe even 0, and as a result, your inputs are overrunning its bounds, causing the value of `N` to change unexpectedly.

Fix it by inputting `N` *before* the declaration of `list`, or else by just declaring `list` with a fixed number of elements large enough to accommodate every acceptable value of `N`.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the non-initialized variable N in a declaration of a variable length array

```
int N; // number of entries

student list[N];
```

So the program has undefined behavior.

Instead you need to write

```
int N; // number of entries

printf("Number of entries: "); scanf("%d", &N);

student list[N];
```

Also in the call of `scanf` remove the new line character `'\n'` from the format string

```
scanf("%d %c %s %s", &list[i].grade, &list[i].gender, list[i].first_name, list[i].last_name);
```

And instead of the function `scanf` you may use the function `scanf_s`.

Comment: *And instead of the function `scanf` you may use the function `scanf_s`.*  That's a lot less portable and not really any safer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Write your remark to the C Standard Committee. It could be useful for you yourself.

Comment: There's an entire question with answers:  [**Why didn't gcc (or glibc) implement _s functions?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724726/why-didnt-gcc-or-glibc-implement-s-functions).  Also [**Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm).  TLDR:  non-portable, slow, not thread-safe, opens up programs to new attacks so really is *less* safe because it allows them to keep running in an indeterminate state after an error.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So is scanf more safe? Then why is the compiler saying that scanf is deprecated?

Comment: [Ummm, who's ***lying*** to you about `scanf()` being "deprecated"?](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4)

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is written in the question.:)